# Ruby: New database columns not being saved but are being read after migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to add new columns to an existing model but when I try to update the values nothing is written to the database.

I have the following input in my view

```
<% if is_auth%>
          <%= f.input :is_startup,  as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Startup' %>   
          <%= f.input :is_hq,  as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Is the Office Headquarters' %>
<% end %>
```

Ive added the is_hq field to the database with a migrate. The problem is that i cant update that field from the view. The is_startup param gets updated but the new is_hq param doesnt. If I run sql in pgadmin to set a value it reads it correctly but i cant change it.

in my controller I have the following update code

```
def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    if @company.update_attributes(company_params)
      flash[:success] = "Data updated"
      redirect_back(fallback_location: edit_page)
    else
      flash[:error] = @company.errors.full_messages
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

There are no required parameters set and in the model I have no validations.

I cant see why any new fields I add aren't getting updated. In the logs I can see the parameters being passed correctly but the commit doenst update the new new field.

Comment: Have you updated `company_params` to include the new fields?

Comment: Im new to ruby so forgive me if this is a stupid question but where can I update company_params to add this new field? Ive done a grep on the enitre code base and the only place its referenced is in the controller and its not set anywhere. I was looking for any definition of strong params but couldnt find anything

Comment: Well of course it was a stupid question! Found it. dont know what I was doing last night when I was searching but it was in another file /controllers/concerns/Company.rb. Thats working now thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to add new columns to an existing model but when I try to
>   update

Probably you just need to run migration: `rake db:migrate`. It's not enough just to add new columns. You have to run migration.

Also, check if your database has these columns. Run `rails dbconsole` (or use other way to log in into your database). Then `use your_db_name;` and `desc your_table;`.

Columns should be present.

Comment: I have already run the db:migrate and the application can read the data from the column it just cant write to it